# Why is tree search costlier than graph search?

Tags: data-structures, artificial-intelligence

Why is tree search considered to be costlier than graph search when a tree can never have a loop and can have only one parent node? Doesn't it mean you can never visit a node more than once if you don't have a loop?

Comment: A tree *is* a graph. If search algorithms for generic graphs were always cheaper, we wouldn't need any algorithms to search trees. But graph algorithms can be *more* expensive. Consider, for example, a binary search tree, which can be searched in O(lg n).

Comment: Related: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/what-is-the-difference-between-tree-search-and-graph-search